# Gradually enforcing style requirements on a code base

Tags: java, jenkins-plugins

I am looking for a good paradigm for gradually enforcing style format requirements on changes to a code base.  I have used checkstyle in the past, but I don't think it will work too well in this case.  The code base is rather large, and I only want to enforce the style requirements on changed code.

We have Jenkins monitoring for pull requests, and runs our unit tests suite against a pull request before we merge them.  Ideally, I would like to run the style checker at the same time we run the unit tests.  Also, we would only want to to see "style violations" in the changed code, not the whole code base.

This is for a Java j2EE web application code base.  The development team uses Eclipse.  Github for our code repository.  Jenkins for continuous integration.

Comment: How about integrating https://www.sonarqube.org for automated code quality checks? I believe you can extract reports for each revision separately.

Comment: I don't think sonarqube is what I am looking for really.  I want to be able to have a configuration file that describe the style rules I want to enforce, and then report back if there are changed lines that break the style rules.